# Distributions fitting, a comparison

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, likelihood-ratio

I tried to make a comparison among various candidate distributions fitting for my data. These data are daily returns of S&P500 US equity Index. Among others I tried with *t-location-scale* ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Generalized_Student's_t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Generalized_Student%27s_t-distribution)) and *t-skewed* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewed_generalized_t_distribution). The first can be viewed as a restricted version of the second. More precisely, at least in the specifications I consider, t-skewed have one parameter more for asymmetry. If this parameter added is zero the two distributions coincide. Therefore I can use the LR test (Likelihood Ratio) for comparison.

In particolar the log-likelihood function (LLF) are: LLF(t-loc-scale)= 16.909,2 and LLF(t-skewed)= 16.914,0. The p-value of related LR test is close to 0,002 therefore the evidence in favour of t-skewed is quite strong. I do not have problem until here, if I miss something please let me know.

Moreover I tried with *Stable* distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution). Unfortunately Stable is not a general and/or particular case of t-skewed. So it remain a comparison between non nested models.

Now my guess start considering that LLF(t-loc-scale) is higher than LLF(Stable)=16.865. Now if we consider that these two distribution is quite similar (at least in this case, see the graph below), become notable that Stable distribution have one parameter more and reach a lower level of LLF in the same data. This sound me as evidence in favour of t-loc-scale. If this reasoning holds we can deduct that, *a fortiori*, t-skewed is better than Stable.

Is this reasoning correct? If it is not, I can conclude something about the comparison between Stable and t-skewed distribution with the output below?

Here the Matlab output:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to fit a parametric distribution as opposed to a nonparametric density estimate if you otherwise just need to describe the distribution of the values with a figure?  Also, such fitting procedures assume independence of observations.  Is that a reasonable assumption for daily returns of the S&P500 US equity Index?

Comment: I have to compare the distributions above and pick the best among them. I know that independence among observations  probably is violated. However there is no reason why some dependance should favor one distribution over another among the above. Actually this point is frequently ignored, sometimes asymptotic argument is used for consider not so relevant dependance issues in sample. In any case my question is only about comparison between not nested distributions.

Comment: I understand "I have to compare the distributions".  But my question is about what do you do with the distribution once you've settled on a "best" distribution.  If just a picture of the distribution is the end result, then it would seem that a nonparametric density would be adequate.  Or maybe you're going to look at change in the estimated parameters over time.  Or maybe you intend to take random samples from that distribution.  In short, stating the purpose as to why you want to compare distributions would be helpful.  (Also, do you have a definition of "nested distributions"?)

Comment: My question is legitimate and well posed. I do not have to justify it. About nested or not nested distribution, the reply is in my question: t-dist is nested in t-skew; stable and t-skew are not nested.

Comment: Your question is fine and I wasn't intending to imply otherwise.  It's just that knowing how you intend to use the result will get you better and more targeted answers.

Comment: One my point is to understand what is better between t-skew and stable for manage skewness in SP500 if any.

Comment: This has well-posed questions but remains a poorly-posed post. If you center the goal in your last comment and streamline the presentation, perhaps you could say: “I want to evaluate trading strategies based on their performance in tail scenarios with few direct observations, so I’d like to choose the strategy with highest VaR under a model of the distribution. I tried fitting models from these three families of distributions, which got these three LLFs…” In any case, I’d like to see a version of this post with that structure.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved some conclusions.

> Is this reasoning correct? If it is not, I can conclude something
> about the comparison between Stable and t-skewed distribution with the
> output below?

Yes it is. Indeed BIC criterion can be applied among non nested models and if the number of parameters is the same, BIC boil down in a comparison among LLF. Therefore, a fortiori, t-location-scale distribution is better than stable one.

Comment: The interpretation is a little off: the slight difference in likelihoods you note is far from convincing or strong evidence, because in any case *both* distributions clearly fail to model the spike in the middle.  If you select t-skewed, you are evidently favoring because it assigns the tiniest bit more probability to the middle bin; but because it's still quite wrong, that might better be taken as an argument for not using t-skewed, either.  It all depends on how you will subsequently be using this fit and how sensitive your results are to this particular kind of error.

Comment: I see your point, but you seems me too severe. Note that the fit curve for t-skew is not plotted, so we cannot see it around the peak. More important, I do not said that t-skew is a good distribution in general. I only said that t-skew is better than alpha stable in LL perspective; and that even t-Stud is better than alpha-stable. I do not said more.

Comment: I am unable to "note" that point because the plot is unclearly labeleled.  I had interpreted the plot as showing the t-skew fit in red.  My point is that relying solely on the log likelihood to evaluate distributional fits, especially when the difference is so slight, might be overlooking better solutions.

Comment: Plot is clear labeled. Names are native from MATLAB and coerently used in the text. Moreover LL values are reported and commented. Read is enough to avoid any confusion. As I already said, I see your point. However I said that your comment as too severe only because my conclusion is not “a bit off” it is admissible, even if the story can go ahead.

Comment: I don't get it: if you are indeed electing to use the t-skew distribution, then why do you illustrate other distributions in your question?  At a minimum, you would want to *look* at your chosen solution to make sure it describes your data sufficiently well for the purposes.

Comment: I wanted to make a comparison among three fitted distribution, in order to select the better one among them. I see that, in LL metric, t-Skew quite better than t-Stud. My doubts was about the fact that comparison between non nested alternatives, like t-skew and alpha stable, is not so easy. However I realize, by BIC, that given results above I can conclude that t-skew is better than alpha stable and even t-Stud is better than alpha stable. That’s all. Conclude that t-skew is a good alternative in general is one step more.

Comment: Thank you for those clarifications.