# What is the distribution of the daily change rates of S&P 500?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, finance

I was wondering what is the distribution of the daily change rates of the S&P 500. It doesn't seem to be distributed normally (using qq plot for example).

Comment: You seem to imply that the stock market should somehow follow some closed form textbook distribution that is readily available in Excel while it is at the same time the result of ever changing influences of human sentiment, warefare, world economics, the ingenuity of people and attempts of manipulation?

Comment: you can see my related question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/546328/distributions-fitting-a-comparison